# Android Overflow Menu Checkbox Color

Tags: android, checkbox, android-toolbar, overflow-menu

Is there a way to change the color of the checkbox in an android overflow menu.

My Current Checkbox is this:

```
 <item android:title="Completed"
    android:checked="false"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:id="@+id/completed"
   >

</item>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be set in your Activity theme

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

Or you could also specifically style your toolbar to override it's own themes like this

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<style name="toolbar_style" parent="">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/toolbar_popup_style</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="toolbar_popup_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent1</item>
</style>
```

then wherever your toolbar layout is

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/toolbar_style"
```